# Add extra columns in the existing csv using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, csv-file

I have a csv file contains around 1000+ rows. I need to add some extra columns in the existing file and also corresponding values of each row of information using jmeter script.Please can someone help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bean shell scripts to execute code that can manipulate CSV files. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788720/how-to-edit-the-csv-file-using-jmeter-means-to-overwrite-the-data-in-the-csv) has an example how to change data in a CSV-file. You should be able to adapt it to adding data aswell.

JMeter is a load testing tool not a CSV manupilation tool. Use other tools to prepare your data. There are a lot of commandline tools you can use to do this, which you could call from within JMeter.

A example flow:

- Initial testdata in prepped in a CVS-file
- JMeter collects data in a file
- Commandline/BeanShell script combines JMeter data with other data into file Y
- JMeter uses new file Y todo something
- More reporting

Your question is not detailed enough to really give a good examle, but hopefully this triggers you to come to a solution for your challenge.

Reads:

- https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell/